# Como montar um VirtualHost básico para reescrever URLs no meu projeto em htdocs Xampp

Tags: apache, xampp, virtualhost

Seguindo o modelo proposto no próprio arquivo *httpd-vhosts.conf*

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host.example.com
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/dummy-host.example.com"
    ServerName dummy-host.example.com
    ServerAlias www.dummy-host.example.com
    ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host.example.com-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/dummy-host.example.com-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seria assim:

```
<VirtualHost projeto:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@projeto
    ServerName projeto

    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/projeto"
    <Directory C:/xampp/htdocs/projeto>
        AllowOverride None
        Order Allow,Deny
        Allow from All

        <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
            Options -MultiViews
            RewriteEngine On
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
            RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
        </IfModule>
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

Depois adicione no seu host o nome "projeto".
Como você está em ambiente Windows: *C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts*

```
   127.0.0.1     projeto
```

Comment: Obrigado. Me ajudou

Answer (score 1):

Duplique essa linha e configure como vc precise no arquivo Httpd-vhosts.conf.
Não esqueça de habilitar o módulo de vhost no Httpd.conf, liberar o listen para a porta do novo virtual host q vc configurou (essas linhas as vezes estão comentadas com #).

Atente-se para as linhas abaixo:

Arquivo **Httpd.conf**:

```
Listen 81
LoadModule vhost_alias_module modules/mod_vhost_alias.so
Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

Reinicie seu XAMP